# Удаление объекта из Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

У меня есть некий сложный объект, состоящий из других объектов. Я хочу удалить этот сложный объект и все объекты из которых он состоит. Но, вызывая метод `realm.delete()`, удаляется только объект этого класса, а те, из которых он состоит, остаются. Прилагаю код.

Создание

```
    Parent parent = new Parent();

    ChildOne one1 = new ChildOne();
    ChildOne one2 = new ChildOne();

    ChildTwo two = new ChildTwo();

    RealmList<ChildOne> list = new RealmList<>();
    list.add(one1);
    list.add(one2);
    parent.setChildrenOne(list);
    parent.setChildTwo(two);

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.insert(parent);
    realm.commitTransaction();
    realm.close();
```

Удаление

```
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.delete(Parent.class);
    realm.commitTransaction();

    realm.close();
```

Comment: ChildOne и Parent связаны между собой?

Comment: Parent содержит список из ChildOne и одно поле типа ChildTwo

Comment: Сначала надо удалить `ChildXXX`, а потом `parent`